# Can hackers spoof or inject form fields?

Tags: sql-server, forms, security

I was going through my app trying to secure it as much as I can and it got me thinking. I always validate my user's input and I always scrub the input, so for example if I have a "birthday" field, I make sure it's a valid date before putting it into the database. But I also have fields in my database like "passwordresettoken", and I have my code generate this field if the user request it.

Now on my normal user profile page, I obviously have no field called "passwordresettoken", so I don't validate or scrub it, because it should not exists in the form that will be passed. In fact, it should never be passed, since it's not something the user would ever input.

So my question is, is it possible to spoof input fields? Could they edit the HTML on my page to include a passwordresettoken field and then do some damage when the form is passed?

Comment: As long as you're not inserting that field into your database, there isn't any way to use it to compromise your database.

Comment: What blender said, and that you are validating input data to prevent injection.

Comment: A user can POST what they want.  There are various tools available for browsers, e.g. [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/), to allow convenient alteration of the data sent for testing purposes.  If you automatically take any posted field and process it, even though it is unexpected, then you could have some interesting issues.  Even expected data may have unexpected values, e.g. a value that you didn't provide in a select list.  Another opportunity exists if form data can be overidden by adding values to the URL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes absolutely. I don't even have to look at your HTML. I can submit directly using curl.

http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html

This html

```
    <form method="POST" action="junk.cgi">
      <input type=text name="birthyear">
      <input type=submit name=press value=" OK ">
    </form>
```

Is equivalent to this curl request

```
curl --data "birthyear=1905&press=%20OK%20" http://www.example.com/junk.cgi
```

Comment: This is assuming that OP is storing the field in a hidden input field. If the value is strictly internal (e.g. a temporary password reset token), this isn't possible.

Comment: I'm assuming the OP is doing something like (pseudocode) ``UPDATE table ('+join(',',keys(GET_VARS))+') ('+join(',',values(GET_VARS))+')'` which is totally dumb but I can see happening.

Comment: @JoeFrambach ok so it's definitely possible then. What is the best course of action here? 1. Check if field exists in the structure submitted, and 2. scrub it?

Comment: Best course of action is to write your sql statements so you explicitly list the fields you want to update.

Comment: Actually, the best course of action is to pass user input using SQL parameters.